# Change Variable in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to change a variable of a BroadcastReceiver. Unfortunately the App crashed everytime I try to access it.

Here is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            setAlarm();
        });
    }

    public void setAlarm(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(),datePicker.getMonth(),datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),timePicker.getCurrentHour(),timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Interval*60000, pi);
    }
}
```

This is the MyAlarm.java Class that extends the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int RecordTimeMinutes;

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //do some stuff
            }
        }, RecordTimeMinutes * 60000);
    }
}
```

So basically I want to acces the Variable RecordTimeMinutes of the MyAlarm class within the MainActivity class. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the variable from the Activity via the Intent extras:

```
public void setAlarm(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(),datePicker.getMonth(),datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),timePicker.getCurrentHour(),timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

        i.putInt("Interval", 42); // Pass "interval" value here

        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Interval*60000, pi);
}
```

And then in the receiver:

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        int interval = intent.getIntExtra("Interval", 0) // Get "interval" value here

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //do some stuff
            }
        }, interval * 60000); // Use "interval" here
    }
}
```

That said - you should *not* be posting a handler to fire in the future inside a BroadcastReceiver. There is no guarantee that your process will still be alive 1 minute from now to execute your code. Instead you could schedule another alarm or use WorkManager to schedule a job to run later.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

For your use-case, why don't you save the value of `RecordTimeMinutes` into a sharedpreference key?

That way you will be able to access it from both the Activity and the Receiver without any issues.

Directly accessing the variable in the activity might not be possible unless you make it static, which is something you **should not** do!